# Euclidean distance using OpenCL

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I am trying to compute the euclidean distance of a set of 5D points (pixels) to a 5D single point (center) and store in another result vector, I want to use vector indexing to store all info in a single vector so for the ith pixel, the 5 dimensions are (5i) , (5i+1) , ...
I am new to OpenCL and I just edited a sample code on the internet for my own intentions. The theory is right but the code doesn't show the right answers !
Here is the **kernel**:

```
//d_kernel.cl

__kernel void distance_kernel(__global double *pixelInfo,
                                __global double *clusterCentres,
                                __global double *distanceFromClusterCentre)
{
    int index = get_global_id(0);

    int d, dl, da, db, dx, dy;

    dl = pixelInfo[5 * index] - clusterCentres[0];
    dl = dl * dl;

    da = pixelInfo[5 * index + 1] - clusterCentres[1];
    da = da * da;

    db = pixelInfo[5 * index + 2] - clusterCentres[2];
    db = db * db;

    dx = pixelInfo[5 * index + 3] - clusterCentres[3];
    dx = dx * dx;

    dy = pixelInfo[5 * index + 4] - clusterCentres[4];
    dy = dy * dy;

    distanceFromClusterCentre[index] = dx + dy + dl + da + db;

}
```

and here is the **HOST CODE**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <CL/cl.h>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

#define MAX_SOURCE_SIZE (0x100000)
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    // Create the two input vectors
    int i;
    const int pixelsNumber = 1024;
    const int clustersNumber = 1;

    std::vector<double> pixelInfo;
    pixelInfo.resize(5 * pixelsNumber);
    std::fill(pixelInfo.begin(), pixelInfo.end(), 500);

    std::vector<double> clusterCentres;
    clusterCentres.resize(5 * clustersNumber);
    std::fill(clusterCentres.begin(), clusterCentres.end(), 200);

    std::vector<double> distanceFromClusterCentre;
    distanceFromClusterCentre.resize(pixelsNumber);
    std::fill(distanceFromClusterCentre.begin(), distanceFromClusterCentre.end(), 0);

    // Load the kernel source code into the array source_str
    FILE *fp;
    char *source_str;
    size_t source_size;

    fp = fopen("d_kernel.cl", "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load kernel.\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    source_str = (char*)malloc(MAX_SOURCE_SIZE);
    source_size = fread(source_str, 1, MAX_SOURCE_SIZE, fp);
    fclose(fp);

    // Get platform and device information
    cl_platform_id platform_id = NULL;
    cl_device_id device_id = NULL;
    cl_uint ret_num_devices;
    cl_uint ret_num_platforms;
    cl_int ret = clGetPlatformIDs(1, &platform_id, &ret_num_platforms);
    ret = clGetDeviceIDs(platform_id, CL_DEVICE_TYPE_DEFAULT, 1,
        &device_id, &ret_num_devices);

    // Create an OpenCL context
    cl_context context = clCreateContext(NULL, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, &ret);

    // Create a command queue
    cl_command_queue command_queue = clCreateCommandQueue(context, device_id, 0, &ret);

    // Create memory buffers on the device for each vector 
    cl_mem pixelInfo_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
        5 * pixelsNumber * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem clusterCentres_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY,
        5 * clustersNumber * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);
    cl_mem distanceFromClusterCentre_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY,
        pixelsNumber * sizeof(int), NULL, &ret);

    // Copy the vectors to their respective memory buffers
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, pixelInfo_mem, CL_TRUE, 0,
        5 * pixelsNumber * sizeof(int), pixelInfo.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);
    ret = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(command_queue, clusterCentres_mem, CL_TRUE, 0,
        5 * clustersNumber * sizeof(int), clusterCentres.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Create a program from the kernel source
    cl_program program = clCreateProgramWithSource(context, 1,
        (const char **)&source_str, (const size_t *)&source_size, &ret);

    // Build the program
    ret = clBuildProgram(program, 1, &device_id, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    // Create the OpenCL kernel
    cl_kernel kernel = clCreateKernel(program, "vector_add", &ret);

    // Set the arguments of the kernel
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&pixelInfo_mem);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 1, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&clusterCentres_mem);
    ret = clSetKernelArg(kernel, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), (void *)&distanceFromClusterCentre_mem);

    // Execute the OpenCL kernel on the list
    size_t global_item_size = pixelsNumber; // Process the entire lists
    size_t local_item_size = 64; // Divide work items into groups of 64
    ret = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(command_queue, kernel, 1, NULL,
        &global_item_size, &local_item_size, 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Read the memory buffer result on the device to the local vector result
    ret = clEnqueueReadBuffer(command_queue, distanceFromClusterCentre_mem, CL_TRUE, 0,
        pixelsNumber * sizeof(int), distanceFromClusterCentre.data(), 0, NULL, NULL);

    // Display the result to the screen
    for (i = 0; i < pixelsNumber; i++)
    {
        cout << "Pixel " << i << ": " << distanceFromClusterCentre[i] << endl;
        //system("PAUSE");
    }

    // Clean up
    ret = clFlush(command_queue);
    ret = clFinish(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseKernel(kernel);
    ret = clReleaseProgram(program);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(pixelInfo_mem);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(clusterCentres_mem);
    ret = clReleaseMemObject(distanceFromClusterCentre_mem);
    ret = clReleaseCommandQueue(command_queue);
    ret = clReleaseContext(context);
    free(pixelInfo.data());
    free(clusterCentres.data());
    free(distanceFromClusterCentre.data());

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

and a part of the **RESULT** is:

```
.
.
.
Pixel 501: -1.11874e+306
Pixel 502: -1.16263e+306
Pixel 503: -1.07485e+306
Pixel 504: -1.03079e+306
Pixel 505: -9.42843e+305
Pixel 506: -9.86903e+305
Pixel 507: -8.98954e+305
Pixel 508: -9.86903e+305
Pixel 509: -8.98954e+305
Pixel 510: -9.43014e+305
Press any key to continue . . .
Pixel 511: -8.55065e+305
Pixel 512: 0
Pixel 513: 0
Pixel 514: 0
Pixel 515: 0
Pixel 516: 0
Pixel 517: 0
Pixel 518: 0
Pixel 519: 0
Pixel 520: 0
.
.
.
```

after index 511 the rest of the vector is zero !

Comment: What result do you get from this code? i.e. What is wrong about it?

Comment: @tobi303 I have updated the post with a part of result !

Comment: rename `nearest_neighbour` to `euclidian_distance_squared`

Comment: Try to learn the OpenCL vector datatypes. Your code can be shortened to 1 or 2 lines with 'float8' points (projecting your 5D-points to a higher level) and constructs like `distanceFromClusterCentre[index] = distance(pixelInfo[index], clusterCentres)`.

Comment: @Christian Thank you for pointing me to an optimization direction, but I have to get the correct result first then optimize my code !

Comment: You're allocating OpenCL buffers sized for ints, but your data vectors are doubles.

Comment: @AmirHosseinF don't call `free` on `vector.data()`. The memory allocation/deallocation is done internally.

Comment: @AmirHosseinF This is the right way of course. My proposal reduces your  code complexity (think of the copy-and-paste-errors). Vector data types are not really an "optimization" in OpenCL, but they are part of its purpose.

Answer (score 1):

You created your vectors of double's and then you treat them as there were ints (created buffer for ints, writing data to int buffers and reading back results as there were ints). To avoid such mistakes you could write your code this way:

```
cl_mem pixelInfo_mem = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, pixelInfo.size() * sizeof(pixelInfo[0]), NULL, &ret);
                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: I am using a `int index = get_global_id(0)` in my kernel ! this should handle a correct indexing I guess. I also followed your suggestion and I replace my own ID with `int index = get_group_id(0)` but the results are still wrong and same with the last one

Comment: you know that a simple `get_global_id` will easily replace a combination of `get_group_id` and `get_local_id` ?

Comment: @AmirHosseinF yep, the problem is not with indexes but with vectors which are created to keep double's you then treat like they were ints. Updated my answer.