# Asynchronous data transfer managed by the kernels in OpenCL?

Tags: c++, c, asynchronous, concurrency, opencl

In my specific problem, I need to evaluate a function with independent variable `x` on the kernels through an interpolation formula that uses data that is held by an array on the host memory. The argument of the function becomes available to each kernel only by the moment that the kernel is executed, as soon as the argument becomes available I would like to stop executing the kernel and move the relevant chunk of data, a `double8` to be specific, from the host to a memory domain on the device that offers the best performance advantage (I think that ideally `local Memory`), in an asynchronously way. I am wondering if I can use and how to use efficiently memory objects to achieve this goal? I am considering the following OpenCL constructs:

```
cl_mem clCreateBuffer( cl_context ctx,
                       cl_mem     flags,
                       syse_t     size,
                       void*      host_ptr,
                       cl_int     errorcode_ret)

err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(
     command_queue,    // command queue managing the transaction
     output,           // buffer object to write to, could it be in local memory?
     CL_TRUE,          // indicating a blocking transfer
     0,                // offset in the output to start writing the data
     size,             // size of the data transfer  
     host_ptr,         // pointer to the buffer in host memory holding the data
     0,                // number of event, what could I do with this?
     NULL,             // number of events that predate the current one? the previous argument, I guess? 
     NULL,             // event object to return after successful completion
     );
```

Following the `OpenCL Best Practices Guide` I would like to use the recommended pattern.

1) *Declare `cl_mem` buffer objects for the pinned host memory and the GPU device GMEM, respectively, and standard pointers to reference pinned host memory.*

```
cl_context cxGPUContext;         // computational context for the current arena
cl_mem cmPinnedBufIn = NULL;     // memory buffer on the host-side 
cl_mem cmDevBufIn = NULL;        // memory buffer on the device-side 
unsigned char* cDataIn = NULL;   // holder for the data buffer
```

2) *Allocate cl_mem buffer objects for the pinned host memory and the GPU device GMEM, respectively* in preparation for the transaction:

```
cmPinnedBufIn = clCreateBuffer(cxGPUContext,                              // computational context for the current arena
                               CL_MEM_READ_ONLY | CL_MEM_ALLOC_HOST_PTR,  // zero-copy I guess??
                               memSize,                                   // size of the stack of memory to hold the data transfers
                               NULL,                                      // initializing the host pointer to NULL
                               NULL);                                     // error code

cmDevBufIn = clCreateBuffer(cxGPUContext,     // computational context for the current arena
                            CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, // read-only mode in the device side 
                            memSize,          // size of the stack of memory to hold the transaction, it is in the Global memory I guess? 
                            NULL,             // initializing the device pointer to NULL
                            NULL);            // error code
```

3) *Map standard pointer to reference the pinned host memory input and output buffers with standard pointers.*

```
cDataIn = (double8 *)clEnqueueMapBuffer(cqCommandQue,  //command queue to manage the data transfer
                                        cmPinnedBufIn, // pinned buffer instantiated avobe
                                        CL_TRUE,       // is this a blocking map?
                                        CL_MAP_WRITE,  // what we are doing? 
                                        0,             // offset in the data 
                                        memSize,       // size of the transfer 
                                        0,             // number of events in the waiting list, howt to capitalize on this?
                                        NULL,          // waiting list  
                                        NULL,          // event
                                        NULL);         // error code
```

4) *Initialize or update the pinned memory content, using the standard host pointer and standard host code.* here I have defined a function to grab from the interpolation table the `double8` corresponding to the independent variable:

```
cDataIn = get_data(x);
```

5) *Write data from pinned host memory to the GPU device GMEM any time in the application that 'fresh' data has been written to the pinned host memory.*

```
err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(
     cqCommandQue,     // command queue managing the transaction
     cmDevBufIn,       // buffer object to write to, could it be in local memory?
     CL_FALSE,         // indicating that this is not a blocking transfer
     0,                // offset in the output to start writing the data
     sizeof(double8),  // size of the data transfer  
     cDataIn,          // pointer to the buffer in host memory holding the data
     0,                // number of event, what could I do with this?
     NULL,             // number of events that predate the current one? the previous argument, I guess? 
     NULL,             // event object to return after successful completion
     );
```

6) *Run computation kernel on the GPU device.* **In this step my application breaks the pattern of more standard computation in the sense that the chunk of data that needs to be transferred to finish the computation depends on the value of `x` here.**  e.g. let us say that the kernel is similar to the one in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30396520/euclidean-distance-using-opencl):

```
//d_kernel.cl

__kernel void distance_kernel(__global double *pixelInfo,
                                __global double *clusterCentres,
                                __global double *distanceFromClusterCentre)
{
    int index = get_global_id(0);

    int d, dl, da, db, dx, dy;

    dl = pixelInfo[5 * index] - clusterCentres[0];
    dl = dl * dl;

    da = pixelInfo[5 * index + 1] - clusterCentres[1];
    da = da * da;

    db = pixelInfo[5 * index + 2] - clusterCentres[2];
    db = db * db;

    dx = pixelInfo[5 * index + 3] - clusterCentres[3];
    dx = dx * dx;

    dy = pixelInfo[5 * index + 4] - clusterCentres[4];
    dy = dy * dy;

    double x = dx + dy + dl + da + db;
    // how could I grab from the host the data corresponding to
    // the value taken by x above?
    // let ussupose that the  inlined function get_data(x) does it
    // 'transparently' :)
    double8 point = get_data(x);
    // use point to compute y by interpolation
    double y = interp(x,point);
    istanceFromClusterCentre[index] = y;

}
```

I am interested only indoing `Host-to-Device` transfers as efficiently as possible. As the `Best practices Guide`  says:

> With the non-blocking read or write transfer, control is returned
>   immediately to the host thread, allowing operations to occur
>   concurrently in the host thread while the transfer between host and
>   device proceeds.

That I naively beleave is the best way to manage this, isn't it? My principal concern is how can be implemented a routine `get_data(x)` that is callable from the kernels to manage efficiently the `Host-to-Device` data transfer? I am also concerned because the allocation of pinned memory might take an appreciable amount of time, how this penalty could be mitigated by allocating an stack of memory at the beginning of the execution? what is the best guess for a good size of the stack?

This statement in the `OpenCL` specification makes me think that what I am asking is possible:

> Global Memory. This memory region permits read/write access to all
>   work-items in all work-groups. Work-items can read from or write to
>   any element of a memory object. Reads and writes to global memory may
>   be cached depending on the capabilities of the device.

But I don't figure out yet how to trigger the data transfer from the kernel. it is, how the `get_data(double x)` should be implemented.

Comment: I cannot figure out what it is that you want to do... I would suggest simplifying your question as much as possible.

Comment: thanks for your message, I am sorry if the contextualization is misleading for you, I want a sequence of code that manages all the steps for grabbing from the host memory to the device memory the right chunk  to interpolate `y` within the kernel, as I explain explicitly in the kernel.

Comment: You would access it the same way you access pixelInfo, clusterCentres and distanceFromClusterCentre. Nothing special about it, just add another parameter to your kernel and bind the argument to your cl_mem buffer. If that's what your question is.

Comment: no, is a bit more complex because I have the data to interpolate` f` in epochs, then to compute the value need to figure pot the right epoch and grab the data from the host to the device. The access pattern to the epochs cannot be predicted beforehand as in the `pixelInfo` that you are mentioning. This is more related to evaluting special mathematical functions within the kernels

Comment: You would have to provide all the possible values that you would need to the kernel beforehand as an array. You cannot dynamically load new data from host to device during kernel execution, since that would totally destroy performance.

Comment: This is not the answer that I am looking for because it does not specify if there is or not a limitation in OpenCL to start a data transfer from the kernel. I think it is possible but I don't figure out how to do it yet.

Comment: There is async_work_group_copy() but only for global and local memory, not for host memory.

Comment: Ok, that seems like progress, but `async_work_group_copy()` will be involved only after answering my question, because I can use `async_work_group_copy()` in order to move the data from global to local memory, I think. But wait a minute, that construct is for cached memory only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/181351/discussion-between-user3116936-and-hugo-maxwell).